# bash scripting: too many arguments in if

Tags: linux, bash

I have an `if` condition within a `for` loop over folders within a given directory, checking if a particular file exists within each folder, and skipping that folder if it doesn't. The `if` condition  gives me a too many arguments error:

```
line 2: [: too many arguments
```

This is my syntax:

```
for folders in path; do
    if [ ! -e /sub/folder/file* ]; then
        continue
    fi
    #do-stuff-to-file
done
```

A similar loop checking for a sub-directory with `! -d` works just fine...

Comment: if you want to find a file, just use `find`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wildcard is the problem. Suppose you have fileA and fileB, it will expand to:

`if [ ! -e /sub/folder/fileA /sub/folder/fileB ]; then`

which is syntactically invalid.